# Подключение шрифтов из поддомена

Tags: шрифты, css

Здравствуйте.
Имеется домен site.com и поддомен subdomain.site.com.
Все стили, скрипты и пр. лежат на главном домене.
При загрузке поддомена подключаю css-файл. А в нем подгружаю шрифты:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'TitilliumText22LMedium';
  src: url('TitilliumText22L004-webfont.eot');
  src: url('TitilliumText22L004-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('TitilliumText22L004-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('TitilliumText22L004-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('TitilliumText22L004-webfont.svg#TitilliumText22LMedium') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Шрифты лежат в одной папке с этим css.
Браузеры ругаются и не хотят их загружать:

```
Font from origin 'http://site.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin    Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://subdomain.site.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

В случае с ajax, помню, нужно было что-то в запросе отправить и ответить. А со шрифтами как?
П.С. Ни на что другое не ругается (css, картинки). Только на этот шрифт.

Comment: А если путь шрифта абсолютными сделать?

Comment: @soledar10, не помогает. Пробовал такие варианты:  
url(/css/TitilliumText22L004-webfont.eot)
url(http://site.com/css/TitilliumText22L004-webfont.eot)